# CSS looping gradient Transition

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-gradients

I got a question please I want to create a CSS looping gradient animation but when I do it the animation is very static it's not animating smoothly below is an example what I'm currently working on. Hope you can help me please.

```css
.slider1 {
  background: background: linear-gradient(rgba(173, 136, 255, 0.44), rgb(109, 0, 255)) !important;
}

/* css animation not smooth */
.slider1 {
  opacity: .5;
  animation: myfirst 5s;
  -moz-animation: myfirst 5s infinite; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 5s infinite; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

@-moz-keyframes myfirst { /* Firefox */ 
  0% {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(173, 136, 255, 0.44), rgb(0, 174, 255))
  }
  50% {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(173, 136, 255, 0.44), rgb(135, 255, 0))
  }
  100% {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(173, 136, 255, 0.44), rgb(109, 0, 255))
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst { /* Safari and Chrome */
  0% {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(173, 136, 255, 0.44), rgb(0, 174, 255))
  }
  50% {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(173, 136, 255, 0.44), rgb(135, 255, 0))
  }
  100% {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(173, 136, 255, 0.44), rgb(109, 0, 255))
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider1">
  This some content
  <div class="wsite-spacer" style="height:600px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can remove vendor-prefixed properties. They are for very old browsers.

Comment: You can't animate gradients like that. Try animating the background-position instead -->https://www.gradient-animator.com/ or look at using pseudoelements --> https://medium.com/@dave_lunny/animating-css-gradients-using-only-css-d2fd7671e759

Comment: Thank you, can you please show me how i could fix my example? I had read the article of dave but I still couldn't figure out how to fix it in my example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

basically your gradint has a fixed color on top, and a varying color in the bottom.

If you construct this gradint as 2 different gradint overlayed, then you can move the one on the bottom and create the changes in color from the changes in position

```css
div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: 
linear-gradient(to top, transparent, red),    
linear-gradient(to right, green, yellow, blue);
    background-size: 100% 100%, 2000% 100%;
    animation: move 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
 from {background-position: center center, left center;}
 to {background-position: center center, right center;}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much this is the best solution and works like a champ! You're amazing thanks so much!

Comment: One thing i noticed it works on all browsers only on Safari macos. I get a glitch do you know how to fix it please ?

Comment: Sorry, I can not test on Safari ... Can you explain what is the glitch ?

Comment: The glitch is now gone.

Sorry, I had an old version of  safari on my mac installed after updating safari your code woks with no glitches 

Thanks so much again

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate `background` but you add blocks with `linear-gradient` and change their `opacity`.

```css
.slider1 {
  opacity: .5;
  position: relative;
}

.frame {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  /* animation for 3 block 5 second each, 3 × 5 = 15 */
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.frame1 {
  animation-name: hide1;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(173, 136, 255, 0.44), rgb(109, 0, 255));
}

.frame2 {
  animation-name: hide2;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(173, 136, 255, 0.44), rgb(135, 255, 0));
}

.frame3 {
  animation-name: hide3;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(173, 136, 255, 0.44), rgb(109, 0, 255));
}

@keyframes hide1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes hide2 {
  33% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  67% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes hide3 {
  67% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider1">
  This some content
  <div class="wsite-spacer" style="height:600px;"></div>
  <div class="frame frame1"></div>
  <div class="frame frame2"></div>
  <div class="frame frame3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is amazing, I just got one last question because I want to apply this gradient loop to a specific slider (Slider Revolution Responsive jQuery) and to get it to work I have to apply the Overlay css color looping on one class only .slider1 that's why I think it wouldn't work on my site if i use .frame and .frame1 but it's an amazing idea if you know how i could apply the same to only one class so it could work with my rev slider jquery that would be very epic